# Converting numbers into alphabets in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a code that would convert numbers into alphabets. For example 1 will be 'A', 2 will be 'B', 3 will be 'C' and so on. Im thinking of writing 26 if statements. I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this...

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to read about the `switch` statement as well. It's not optimal in this case, but it's often a good replacement for a large chain of if-statements.

Answer (score 30):

Use an array of letters.

```
char nth_letter(int n)
{
    assert(n >= 1 && n <= 26)
    return "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[n-1];
}
```

Comment: thanks for responding to my post. Sure it would help me and to all those who would ask the same question.

Comment: if this solves your issue, you should accept it as best answer

Answer (score 9):

If you can rely on the using an ASCII character set where they are consecutive then you can convert

```
char intToAlphabet( int i )
{
   return static_cast<char>('A' - 1 + i);
}
```

If you can sometimes rely on this fact, e.g. you can set a compiler flag or similar for the particular target, you can also use this code for that specific build.

Otherwise use a static lookup table (as others have suggested).

Note that it is preferable to "assert" your range check if your numbered input comes from program variables that you know should never be out of range.

If the input comes from user-provided data where the users could potentially provide rogue data, you need a way to handle it that is not "undefined behaviour". Therefore you would have to check each value and either throw an exception (informing the user to correct their data) or use some character to indicate a bad input.

Comment: You can't rely on ASCII.  (In fact, I don't know of any system today which uses ASCII.  And the alphabetic characters aren't contiguous in Latin 1 (probably the most widely used single byte encoding).  And in EBCDIC (used on IBM mainframes) even the 26 unaccented alpha characters aren't contiguous.

Comment: You can probably check statically that the above works and use your solution if it doesn't. When the above works it is likely to be higher performance as the compiler will almost certainly inline this, and if you're doing millions of these it might make a difference.

Comment: thanks for responding to my post. Sure it would help me and to all those who would ask the same question.

Comment: If the profiler tells you that the function call is a bottleneck, you can always change it, but I'm not sure how you can tell statically, and the table solution allows for any imaginable encoding.

Comment: @CashCow: When posting this non-portable code, you (imho) _should_ do a static check or have a disclaimer.

Comment: I did do a disclaimer. I said "if you can rely on the ASCII character set being consecutive".

Comment: @CashCow You can rely on the ASCII character set being consecutive, but you can't rely on the character encoding being ASCII.

Comment: I know I reworded it to say what I really meant.

Comment: @JamesKanze: if you are returning a `char` in C++, aren't we implicitly using ASCII?

Answer (score 3):

something like that

```
my_print(int x)
{
    char symbol = (char)('A' + x - 1);
    cout << symbol;
}
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that the alphabetic characters be contiguous, and in fact, in some encodings (EBCDIC), they aren't.

Comment: thanks for responding to my post. Sure it would help me and to all those who would ask the same question.

Comment: You don't need the -1 in that symbol.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be using a table:

```
char
remap( int original )
{
    static char const remap[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    return original >= 0 && original < sizeof(remap) - 1
        ? remap[ original ]
        : '?';   // or throw, or ...
}
```

Comment: I like your solution in a "static" version where you cannot guarantee the characters are consecutive conversions. I would prefer asserts to the range check though if this needs to be in high performance code.

Comment: thanks for responding to my post. Sure it would help me and to all those who would ask the same question.

Comment: @CashCow And how can you determine anything statically?  The fact that the last element of the table minus the first is equal to one less than the length of the table doesn't mean that all of the intermediate values are in range.  And depending on the system, this might actually be faster than something like `'A' + original`.  (More likely on older systems, but you never know.)

Comment: I'd be quite interested to know in how one could rely on sorting strings properly if you can't guarantee your characters appear in alphabetical order. It might make sense to have an arrangement AaBbCcDdEe etc. so you even get insensitive sort correct but if 'Z'-'A'==25 it's difficult to know what you'd put in the middle to enforce it to work.

Comment: @CashCow The definition of "sorting" in C++ doesn't usually correspond to anything outside of the programming world, at least in `"C"` and `"POSIX"` locales.  The comparison functions of `std::string` certainly don't do anything useful for actual human language text.

Comment: sorting of a std::string is done through type_traits<char> which provides a comparison function, which is why they recommend if you want to do case-insensitive comparison you do it through type_traits, although that means defining a new string as basic_string<char,type_traits<char>,allocator<char> > and basic_string<char,insensitive_traits<char>,allocator<char> > are unrelated types. Better would be to provide your own predicate and this can be done non-intrusively and fairly easily with a static table.

Comment: @CashCow Sorting of an `std::string` is done through `std::type_traits<char>`, which is case sensitive (or more correctly, sorts according to the integer value of the `char`).  There's nothing you can do about that.  And creating a new type with case insensitive compare isn't necessarily a good idea, see http://lafstern.org/matt/col2_new.pdf.  The "correct" solution should be to use `std::sort` with the `std::collate` facet from the appropriate locale, but the standard sort of blew this one: `std::collate` only works on `char const*`.

Comment: By the way your solution is slightly incorrect his conversion is 1 based so you need to check original > 0 and original < sizeof(remap) then return remap[ original-1]

Comment: can you post the right one Mr CashCow? cause when compile it, the output is incorrect. Also, could you explain that part after the "return" word? cause I really can't understand why did it come to be like that. Thanks

Comment: I mean this line: return original >= 0 && original < sizeof(remap) - 1
        ? remap[ original ]
        : '?';

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert `0` to `a`, `1` to `b`, `2` to `c` ... `25` to `z`:

```
char covertedChar = (char)('a' + 2);
// Will print 'c'
cout << covertedChar;
```

Similary, to convert `0` to `A`, `1` to `B`, `2` to `C` ... `25` to `Z`:

```
char covertedChar = (char)('A' + 25);
// Will print 'Z'
cout << covertedChar;
```

So if you want to convert `1` to `A`, `2` to `B`, `3` to `C` ... `26` to `Z`, simply subtract `1` offset.

```
int toCovert = 26 // 'Z'
char covertedChar = (char)('A' + toCovert - 1);
// Will print 'Z'
cout << covertedChar;
```